# CallKit CXCallAction Transactions Hanging

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native, callkit

I'm working on a React Native voip app which uses [PJSip](https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip) and [CallKeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep). Callkeep uses CallKit internally to handle calls on iOS devices, so this is really more of a CallKit question.

From what I've seen via documentation and my apps logs, a normal CallKit flow will perform the following:

- A transaction with a **CXStartCallAction** is called
- **CXStartCallAction** completion handler is called
- **performStartCallAction** delegate method is triggered
- ...call continues for some time...
- A transaction with a **CXEndCallAction** is called
- **CXEndCallAction** completion handler is called
- **performEndCallAction** delegate method is triggered

However, I've noticed that if the transaction with a **CXStartCallAction** is called and then a **CXEndCallAction** transaction is called *before* the **CXStartCallAction** transaction completes, the **performStartCallAction** delegate method never gets triggered and the app hangs. So rather than the above, this is what I see happening:

- A transaction with a **CXStartCallAction** is called
- A transaction with a **CXEndCallAction** is called
- **CXEndCallAction** completion handler is called
- App hangs...no further logs until I kill the app and restart

I'm primarily a JS programmer and have been learning Objective C on the side, so I may be missing something. Why doesn't the **CXStartCallAction** transaction complete, and why is the app hanging?